# looking for one criteria in more columns

Tags: sql

database noob here, how would you look for a search criteria in more columns, which are Possibly containing that word? I have for example 3 container columns, and im looking for records where in any of these one certain container number/name is appearing. Because of the structure of the database, the container number is just appearing in one of these columns, but i need all the records where it might appear.
sorry for bad english,
cheers

Comment: What's your exact question about this? Why not search through all three columns using an `OR` condition?

Comment: If you struggle with your attempts, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: combine your where-conditions with an OR

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @Table
WHERE '|' + A + '|' + B + '|' + C + '|' like '%foobar%'
```

will for a table with columns A,B and C join the results of the 3 and see which rows contain foobar somewhere in between

example:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    A VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    B VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    C VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO @Table (A,B,C)
Values ('aaa',    'bb',  'cc'),
       ('foobar', 'bb',  'cc'),
       ('foo',    'bar', 'cc')


SELECT *
FROM @Table
WHERE '|' + A + '|' + B + '|' + C + '|' like '%foobar%'
```

will only return you the second row as it's the only where foobar is mentioned.
Notes:

1. i'm assuming '|' is not used but you can replace by a different character if it is
2. if you want the content to be exactly foobar you can use `like '%|foobar|%'`